# How to map data in dygraph by applying conditions based on the data?

Tags: javascript, csv, time-series, dygraphs

I have this CSV data which I want to map in my dygraph time series graph.

```
_time                 value Id  provider
2022-09-20T10:43:00Z    1   1   x
2022-09-20T10:43:15Z    2   1   x
2022-09-20T10:43:30Z    3.2 1   x
2022-09-20T10:43:45Z    4   1   x
2022-09-20T10:44:00Z    4.1 1   x
2022-09-20T10:44:15Z    5   1   x
2022-09-20T10:43:00Z    2   2   y
2022-09-20T10:43:15Z    4   2   y
2022-09-20T10:43:30Z    4.5 2   y
2022-09-20T10:43:45Z    4   2   y
2022-09-20T10:44:00Z    5   2   y
2022-09-20T10:44:15Z    6   2   y
```

this throws an error while trying to graph the data.
I want to be able to plot the time series graph in such a data type:

```
time                        x   y
2022-09-20T10:43:00Z        1   2
2022-09-20T10:43:15Z        2   4
2022-09-20T10:43:30Z        3.2 4.5
2022-09-20T10:43:45Z        4   4
2022-09-20T10:44:00Z        4.1 5
2022-09-20T10:44:15Z        5   6
```

this data could show the graph that I want. but I can't seem to work with dygraph. PS the time being showed may not be the perfect time data but I will be implementing the normal data type in future.

I'm ready to implement the original data and configure it with dygraph or even change the data structure. let me know if I can give even more examples to convey my problem more properly.

Comment: Why don't you parse the data with a script to convert it from the original format to the required one? I understand that you need help doing this parsing, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by a 'normal' data type. So this may not be what you're looking for. I also don't know what type of graph you're trying to make with Dygraphs.

However, I've added some code here that might be helpful. Since I can't attach a CSV to an SO Answer, I've added the data to a `pre` tag in the HTML.

```js
dta = document.getElementById('externalCsvData').innerHTML;

g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('graphdiv'),
  dta);
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.2/dygraph.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dygraph/2.1.2/dygraph.min.css"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    The data plotted with Dygraphs.
  </p>
  <div id="graphdiv"></div>
  <pre id="externalCsvData" style="display:none;">
time,x,y
2022-09-20 10:43:00,1.0,2.0
2022-09-20 10:43:15,2.0,4.0
2022-09-20 10:43:30,3.2,4.5
2022-09-20 10:43:45,4.0,4.0
2022-09-20 10:44:00,4.1,5.0
2022-09-20 10:44:15,5.0,6.0
</pre>
</body>
```